# How to run ROS 2 on Kobuki Turtlebot 2

Tags: ros2, turtlebot2, kobuki, turtlebot-bringup

I have a Turtlebot 2 (with Kobuki base) that hasn't been used in a while. I will like to work with it using ROS 2. My first goal is the get it to the point where I can run simple applications on it and get it to move around.

The original ASUS laptop that came with it appears to be dead and I am trying to recreate the environment of the ASUS laptop on another laptop. For now, this other laptop is running Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble installed.

What else do I need to install?
What other steps do I need to take to get the turtlebot moving?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a very similar exercise with my Kobuki Turtlebot2. I was able to get it to navigate with Nav2 on ROS2 Iron. I used a docker container, and I put the dockerfile along with the bringup and description packages I created on github: https://github.com/ingotrobotics/turtlebot2_ros2. I used a Hokuyo URG-04 as the navigation sensor, so if you have something else, you'll need to add that to the container.

That should get you up and running pretty quickly, but it may not be what you want to do. If you just want to control the Kobuki base, you'll have to build from source because the Kobuki driver node has not been released as an apt package for 22.04 as of yet. You can follow the instructions in the Kobuki documentation: https://kobuki.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0.x/software.html. You can then pull in the ROS1 Turtlebot2 description files as you need.